# php mysql error trying to get email verification - phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmyadmin, verification

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/24.html
**I am following the guide above.**

**I put in these codes after i made the correct tables**

```
Table "temp_members_db"
CREATE TABLE `temp_members_db` (
`confirm_code` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
`country` varchar(65) NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
```

---

```
`Table "registered_members"
CREATE TABLE `registered_members` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`email` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`country` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**My signup.php:**

```
<table width="350" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="signup_ac.php">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Sign up</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="76">Name</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="305"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>E-mail</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="country" type="text" id="country" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> &nbsp;
<input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**My signup_ac.php:**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

// table name
$tbl_name=temp_members_db;

// Random confirmation code
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

// Insert data into database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, name, email, password, country)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email
if($result){

// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------


// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;

// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";

// From
$header="from: your name <your email>";

// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="http://www.yourweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";


// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

}


// if not found
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}


// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}

?>
```

**My confirmation.php:**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

// Passkey that got from link
$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];

$tbl_name1="temp_members_db";

// Retrieve data from table where row that match this passkey
$sql1="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code ='$passkey'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

// If successfully queried
if($result1){

// Count how many row has this passkey
$count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

// if found this passkey in our database, retrieve data from table "temp_members_db"
if($count==1){

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$name=$rows['name'];
$email=$rows['email'];
$password=$rows['password'];
$country=$rows['country'];

$tbl_name2="registered_members";

// Insert data that retrieves from "temp_members_db" into table "registered_members"
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(name, email, password, country)VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}

// if not found passkey, display message "Wrong Confirmation code"
else {
echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
}

// if successfully moved data from table"temp_members_db" to table "registered_members" displays message "Your account has been activated" and don't forget to delete confirmation code from table "temp_members_db"
if($result2){

echo "Your account has been activated";

// Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db" that has this passkey
$sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}

}
?>
```

**And finally my config.php:**

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name


//Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

?>
```

The error i receive on signup_ac.php:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'vhostswww'@'MYIP I THINK' (using password: NO) in /www/kkk.org/k/k/k/kkkhits/htdocs/config.php on line 12
cannot connect to server
```

Comment: You haven't asked any question

Comment: too many problems in your code !!

Comment: too many code!!  Simplify, man.

Comment: You did not post the Error which you got.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code, but at least fix the SQL injection!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use need to do something like this, Look at the stars ;)  --

EDIT --

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name


//Connect to server and select database.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$con)or die("cannot select DB");

?>
```

Comment: what database name do i use temp_members_db or  registered_members

Comment: @XavierD you better know which database you are using temp_members_db or registered_members  :)